# WebAssembly directive ignored for next.config.mjs and getting error

Tags: webpack, next.js, webassembly, mdxjs

I'm trying to migrate my site to mdx2 and mdx-embed.
I'm running into issues with webpack not recognizing my web-assembly configuration in `next.config.mjs`. The issue is happening during the import of wasm file during the "yarn build".

```
Import trace for requested module:
./wasm/fulltext-search/pkg/fulltext_search_core.js
./components/Search/Search.tsx
./components/Search/index.tsx
./pages/articles/index.tsx
```

Here is my migration branch below:

https://github.com/hanymorcos/hanymorcos.github.io/tree/next_config_mjs_mdx2

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

./wasm/fulltext-search/pkg/fulltext_search_core_bg.wasm
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
The module seem to be a WebAssembly module, but module is not flagged as WebAssembly module for webpack.
BREAKING CHANGE: Since webpack 5 WebAssembly is not enabled by default and flagged as experimental feature.
You need to enable one of the WebAssembly experiments via 'experiments.asyncWebAssembly: true' (based on async modules) or 'experiments.syncWebAssembly: true' (like webpack 4, deprecated).
For files that transpile to WebAssembly, make sure to set the module type in the 'module.rules' section of the config (e. g. 'type: "webassembly/async"').
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the configuration to enable WebAssembly under the `webpack` configuration, not in Next.js configuration object root.

```js
module.exports = {
    // Your other Next.js configs

    webpack: function (config, { isServer }) {
        // Your other webpack configs

        config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, asyncWebAssembly: true }

        return config
    }
}
```

See the official Next.js [WebAssembly example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-webassembly/next.config.js).

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. it didnt' work. I've been trying stuff out for the last 24 hours and not difference. https://github.com/hanymorcos/hanymorcos.github.io/blob/next_config_mjs_mdx2/next.config.mjs

Comment: Also, I'm not using commonjs, I'm using ES module. Because I want to configure mdx2.